# Is it possible to do meta programming in Swift

Tags: swift, metaprogramming

Is there a way to dynamically generate methods in a class like in Ruby in Swift? Can this be done by setting instance variables to be a function like in Javascript.

Comment: I think it is not possible because opposite ObjC, Swift is designed to be (more) static language that most of the work are done at compile-time (so compiler can detect error first). But without more details from Apple, I can't be sure.

Comment: There is concept of functions being a type so it could be possible to assign function to a instance variable. So if we can dynamically generate an instance variable in a class it might be possible

Comment: that sounds like C struct of function pointers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book [The Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11) doesn't mention anything.

As that is the definitive guide to the language we have right now, this seems like bad luck. As swift is based on the ObjC language runtime however, which has metaprogramming abilities, there ought to be some way to do it.

So lets wait and see.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add there is a method called `reflect` that lets you get the properties of an object, but not much more that so far.

http://genius.com/Soroush-khanlou-metaprogramming-isnt-a-scary-word-not-even-in-objective-c-annotated